# How to backup and restore a named docker volume containing MongoDB data

Tags: mongodb, docker, backup

I have a docker image for my mongoDB. I want to make a script that backup production data, and restore it in my local machine, so that I can have a dev environment similar to production.

Here is a part of my `docker-compose.yml`

```
 mongo:
    image: "mongo:latest"
    container_name: "espace_client_mongo"
    volumes:
      - mongo-data:/data/db
```

I want to export data contained in `mongo-data` volume.

Docs state that I can do it with:

```
 docker run --rm --volumes-from dbstore -v $(pwd):/backup ubuntu tar cvf /backup/backup.tar /dbdata
```

but I can't make it work.

When I run it, I get:

```
ec2-user@espace-client-prod prod]$ docker run --rm --volumes-from espace_client_mongo -v $(pwd):/backup ubuntu tar cvf /backup/backup.tar ./backup
tar: ./backup/backup.tar: file is the archive; not dumped
./backup/
./backup/Caddyfile
./backup/docker-compose.yml
[ec2-user@espace-client-prod prod]$ ls
backup.tar  Caddyfile  docker-compose.yml
```

It will put the files in current folder into a backup folder. This is not what I want. I want to put the content of docker volume in the backup folder. Am I misunderstanding something ?

EDIT: I would like to backup and restore data with mongo tools ( mongodump and mongorestore)

Comment: just bind another volume as backup to a custom-directory inside mongo container. and then go inside mongo container and take the backup by mongodump command inside that custom directory. so you can also download backup data inside volume by cp command. and when you want to restore data you can bind the directory that have the data to a directory in mongo container and use mongorestore to restore the data

Answer (score 7):

You can find the data you want to backup in the directory `/var/lib/docker/volumes/mongo-data/_data`¹ on your host machine. This is what you have at `/data/db` inside your container.

You don't have to run an additional Docker container just to backup your data if you already have them as a volume. So you only need to run `sudo tar cvzf backup.tar.gz /var/lib/docker/volumes/mongo-data/_data` from your host machine.

**UPDATE**

Since you want to use `mongodump`, just follow [the official documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo) for the Docker image you're using:

```
$ docker exec some-mongo sh -c 'exec mongodump -d <database_name> --archive' > /some/path/on/your/host/all-collections.archive
```

---

¹ Note that this volume might have another name, probably prefixed with the folder's name from where you run the `docker-compose.yml` if you didn't define anything else.

Comment: This is a possibility, but as I need it to backup database, it would be better to use mongodump and mongorestore to avoid corrupted data, it was quite easy with mounted volumes

Comment: That makes perfect sense, but wasn't part of your question. I'll update my answer soon.

Comment: Ok, you are right, I will add it to my question. So, I think the main issue is not to dump, but to restore. I think my question needs some refactoring. I think main issue is not dump, but restore because of the named volume, do you know how should I restore ?

Comment: [This blog post](https://blog.studiointeract.com/mongodump-and-mongorestore-for-mongodb-in-a-docker-container-8ad0eb747c62) should get you going.

Answer (score 1):

I use this command to backup the data from the container, note the directory "/data/db".

```
docker run --rm \
  --volumes-from espace_client_mongo \
  -v $(pwd):/backup \
  ubuntu bash -c "cd /data/db && tar cvf /backup/backup.tar ."
```